# regex to match optional prefix

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of text that will look like

```
 · 7:30pm · a/a · ★★ · fri sold out · Multi-day event ·
```

or

```
 · 7:30pm · a/a · ★★ · sold out · Multi-day event ·
```

I want to capture `sold out` if that text exists or `fri sold out` if that text exists.

My attempted regex is `/^.*\s(\w*\ssold out|sold out).*$/` but that is only capturing `sold out`.

How do I capture either string of text?

**Edit**: I will not always have the `·` anchors on either side. I also want to be able to grab the same info from, i.e.:

```
10pm · 21+ · ★ · late show - sold out ·
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nD2wB2/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. The problem with your pattern is the first `.*`

By default, the regex engine is greedy, `.*` consumes as much as it can, and it has precedence over the rest of the pattern (it's on the left). To change this behaviour, you can use a [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy). Adding the extra "?" in `.*?` makes it repeat as few as possible.

```
/^.*?\s(\w*\ssold out|sold out).*$/
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fN3wR1/1)</kbd>

---

Now that we made clear what was wrong, let's see a few more things. I think `\w*` should require at least 1 char, so we can change the quantifier and use `\w+`. Also, we can make it shorter using a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to make the `\w*\s` optional, thus shortening the pattern:

```
/^.*?\s((?:\w+\s)?sold out).*$/
```

And if you don't actually need to match the whole line, you can use:

```
/\s((?:\w+\s)?sold out)/
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fN3wR1/2)</kbd>

Comment: Another tip, if you want to make it shorter: `/^.*?\s((?:\w*\s)?sold out).*$/`

Comment: Even the updated version is more complicated than it needs to be. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, but I preferred to simply point where the OP's regex was failing, instead of adding new concepts... And we don't know if the OP needs to match the whole line for some reason, nor we don't know if he/she is validating text in multiline mode.

Answer (score 4):

You can capture an optional `\w+` in front of `sold out` (fortunately, have that nice solid `sold out` to work with):

```
var rex = /((?:[\w]+ )?sold out)/;
var match = str.match(rex);
var text = match && match[1];
```

**Live Example:**

```js
test("· 7:30pm · a/a · ★★ · fri sold out · Multi-day event ·");
test("· 7:30pm · a/a · ★★ · sold out · Multi-day event ·");
test("10pm · 21+ · ★ · late show - sold out ·");
function test(str) {
  var rex = /((?:[\w]+ )?sold out)/;
  var match = str.match(rex);
  var text = match && match[1];
  snippet.log("'" + str + "' =>");
  snippet.log("'" + text + "'");
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

[Here's an explanation of that regex](https://regex101.com/r/lA5mS3/1), but basically the outer `(...)` is a capture group, then `(?:[\w]+ )?` says "*optionally* match one or more word characters followed by a space" (the `?` after the non-capturing group `(?:...)` is what makes it optional), and of course `sold out` is our anchoring text.

Answer (score 1):

```
★+\s*\·\s*([^·]+)(?=·)
```

You can use this and grab the `group`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/1

```
var re = /★+\s*\·\s*([^·]+)(?=·)/g; 
var str = ' · 7:30pm · a/a · ★★ · fri sold out · Multi-day event ·\n\nor\n\n · 7:30pm · a/a · ★★ · sold out · Multi-day event ·';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```